# How to make a div match an exact point of the background?

Tags: css

I have a container that has a background image. I also have a few divs pointing at exact locations relative to the background. I can do that using left-top attributes. But the problem is the container has 60% width and 500px for min-width. Resizing the browser window messes up the divs' locations.

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:60%;
    height:550px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-275px 0 0 -30%;
    min-width:500px;
    border: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) solid 1px;

}
.main-content{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(../img/map.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:90% auto;
    background-mi
}

.loc1-point{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:18.5%;
    top:14.5%;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-content">
         <div class="loc1-point"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BHCbg/) to give you the idea. But the point on the map moves around a lot more during re-sizing of an actual browser window.
I can add the image as an img element, then put the points over it, but all I want is to have my points in certain locations and have the same look in all sizes of the container.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to put that dot on the image itself (with image editor)? Or use google maps api

Comment: @jonasnas I cant put that on the image by image editors as each point will have some effects with jquery and also there are more stuff that will be added like lightbox after clicking each and so on. This is just a simplified version.

Comment: Put the image in a div (or make it the background), style the div with position: absolute. Make a second div with position absolute and with top and left pick a spot on the map where you want it. It will stay "fixed" to the map. Here's a fiddle with a red dot on Piazza del Popolo. http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2zqd9/

Comment: @TimSPQR thanks for your help. But the point is I want to have percentage for the width of the image(map) so its size will decrease in smaller screens. Therefore the point must also change its location accordingly.

Comment: wouldn't percentage in top/left work in that case?

Comment: Percentage or pixels...don't you want the point fixed on the map?

Comment: @jonasnas What case do you mean?

Comment: @TimSPQR Yes exactly I want it to be fixed in the map. So if the map size changes, the point location changes too. If thats possible can you show it on JSFiddle?! the one that u linked has size in pix but I my case is in percentage. So it gets more space in a bigger screen that small ones.

Comment: @TimSPQR http://jsfiddle.net/2zqd9/1/ Checkout the location of the red poin, then try to change the screen size. As you can see see the point will not stay where is supposed to to be.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll propose an answer, and let's see how convincing it is.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2zqd9/2/) has the following:

1. A div at a particular size.
2. A background image of a map sized to the same size as the div
3. A second div (the marker) inside the first div
4. The marker's position is adjusted by % - right on the Piazza del Popolo

HTML

```
<div class='firstdiv'>
<div class='seconddiv'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.firstdiv {
    background: url(http://www.centralromehotels.net/map/rome_map.jpg);
    background-size: 500px 400px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
.seconddiv {
    width:            10px;
    height:           10px;
    background-color: red;
    position:         relative;
    top:              11%;
    left:             47%;
}
```

So the key is a "fixed" map in a container, and a marker adjusted relatively.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but the first div which has the map as the background does not have a percentage size. So in any screen its size is 500px X 400X. But I want it to be in percentage, like 60%, so in a bigger screen, the map will be bigger than a very small screen. In this case the location of the marker show change relatively.